# How to update json object in Postgres for current time in epoch

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I need to update a json object for the 'lastUpdated' field with the current time in Epoch. I am doing the following but it is failing:

```
UPDATE data SET data = data  || '{"lastUpdated": extract(epoch from current_timestamp) }'
 WHERE dtype='Employee' and data->>'id' = '1234';
```

The following itself doesn't work:

```
UPDATE data SET data = data  || '{"lastUpdated": current_timestamp }'
 WHERE dtype='Employee' and data->>'id' = '1234';
```

I am getting 'invalid input syntax for type json'.

Please note, the following works when i set a custom epoch time:

```
UPDATE data SET data = data  || '{"dateAdded":1447502107000 , "lastUpdated":1447502107000}' WHERE dtype='Employee' and data->>'id' = '1234';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should alter the data type of the column `data` to `jsonb`, as [the concatenation operator `||`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) does not work with `json`.

```
alter table data alter data type jsonb;
```

Then use the function `jsonb_build_object()`:

```
UPDATE data SET data = data || jsonb_build_object('lastUpdated', extract(epoch from current_timestamp))
WHERE dtype='Employee' and data->>'id' = '1234';
```

If you do not want to change the column type, you have to use casting:

```
UPDATE data SET data = data::jsonb || jsonb_build_object('lastUpdated', extract(epoch from current_timestamp))
WHERE dtype='Employee' and data->>'id' = '1234';
```

---

Update

Choose one of the two variants to round or get rid of precision of timestamp:

```
select
    extract(epoch from current_timestamp),
    replace(extract(epoch from current_timestamp::timestamp(3))::text, '.', ''),
    concat(extract(epoch from current_timestamp::timestamp(0))::text, '000')

    date_part     |    replace    |    concat     
------------------+---------------+---------------
 1533560841.14562 | 1533568041146 | 1533568041000
(1 row)
```

Alternatively:

```
select
    extract(epoch from current_timestamp),
    extract(epoch from current_timestamp(3))* 1000 as v1,
    extract(epoch from current_timestamp(0))* 1000 as v2
```

Comment: Thanks.I have edited my post. Actually, the query does work when I set a custom epoch time i.e. the || operator works with the json. Nevertheless, I tried your last query and it works but when i see the data in the field, it is 1533558723.808. Can i get rid of the decimal point. I need it to be 1533558723808.

Comment: *Actually, the query does work when I set a custom epoch time i.e. the || operator works with the json* - well I do not think we use the same Postgres. [SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c612/2)

Comment: Yup, my bad. I just checked the table description. The data field is indeed jsonb. Thanks for pointing out. Can you please let me know how to I get rid of the precision? I tried using extract(epoch from current_timestamp)*1000, but it then appends another two digits at the end after the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because extract is a function and by using it inside '', you are basically sending a string, which returns you timestamp

```
UPDATE data SET data = data  || '{"lastUpdated": extract(epoch from 
current_timestamp) }'
WHERE dtype='Employee' and data->>'id' = '1234';
```

Meanwhile this works because you are storing the way it is meant to store

```
UPDATE data SET data = data  || '{"dateAdded":1447502107000 , 
"lastUpdated":1447502107000}' WHERE dtype='Employee' and data->>'id' = '1234';
```

Though I would say to try Klin's way, but the solution to what you are asking can also be (make sure you change the data type to JSONB):

```
UPDATE data SET data = data  || '{"lastUpdated":' || extract(epoch from 
current_timestamp)::text || '}'
WHERE dtype='Employee' and data->>'id' = '1234';
```